# Multi-column text display on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What is the best way of implementing a multi-line + multi-column text display?

HTML? Tables?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML to display the text, webkit, (the iPhone HTML rendering engine) supports the multi-column CSS properties.

You can read about them at http://webkit.org/blog/88/css3-multi-column-support/ ...

Answer (score -1):

I would go with UITableView and subclass the cells and put UILabels (for noneditable), or UITextView (for editable) as nessessary to create the column layout you want. I've done this and it works good. Just make sure you subclass the cell and don't try to add the label or textView to the cell on every call for cellAtIndexPath. That will sevearly reduce performance.